# MongoDB+PHP+cursor.forEach() - any workarounds?

Tags: php, mongodb, mapreduce

I'm doing some complex data processing on multiple entries in MongoDB, first I do map/reduce/finalize, and then I need to execute some other logic to calculate and write totals and other figures that are impossible to calculate within the map/reduce itself.

I've created a separate JS function to run through `db.eval()` that does what I need to do, but I've just discovered that `db.eval()` is deprecated in MongoDB 3.0, and this is a bummer for me, because I have a plan on upgrading to 3.0 shortly, we really need it's new WiredTiger engine.

I've looked at the `db.cursor.forEach()` function as another way to implement similar logic, but it seems like it's not supported in the current MongoDB PHP driver.

So the question is - are there any workarounds for executing complex per-document functions in the Mongo-PHP stack?

Comment: `eval` is deprecated in 3.0 because it's generally terrible. It's been decided to get rid of it rather than keep it for the rare cases where it's ok to use. Would you consider providing some more information about the calculations you're trying to do, so we can determine if there's a good way to do them with the aggregation framework? You should see an order of magnitude difference between eval and aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

Mongo's MapReduce is implemented using JavaScript, the [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/) is based on C++ and much faster for me. Have you considered using the Aggregation Framework?

Comment: Well, things I need to do are not possible within just aggregation framework itself. It's probably possible using a mixture of several different aggregation pipelines with addition of PHP intermediary logic, which probably will be no much faster in the end, and definitely much more hairy and unmaintainable.
So I would prefer to keep all heavy data processing in JS on the Mongo side.

Comment: Right now I've decided to proceed with `db.eval()`, since it's still available in 3.0 (although deprecated). It's not ideal, but other available solutions seem to be even worse.